Docker fails to update node_modules after dependency changes in package.json
I'm experiencing an issue where Docker doesn't seem to update the node_modules folder after I modify dependencies in package.json. Even after rebuilding the Docker image and container, the application still throws errors related to the missing dependencies. The changes to node_modules only take effect if I completely remove the container and its associated volume before rebuilding.
Dockerfile:
FROM node:22-alpine

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

USER node

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  npm-test:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules_docker:/app/node_modules

volumes:
  node_modules_docker:

Steps to reproduce:

Build and run the container (everything works):
docker compose up --build


Remove significant dependencies from package.json e.g. @vitejs/plugin-react

Run npm install to update package-lock.json

Stop and remove the container, images, and volumes, then rebuild (use the following commands to delete everything, or replace IDs to target specific ones):
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)

docker compose up --build


The following error will show up:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@vitejs/plugin-react' imported from /app/node_modules/.vite-temp/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1733299382139-6e1c72bf771df.mjs

Add back the missing dependencies to package.json and run npm install

Build and run the container again:
docker compose up --build


The app should work again (it is "the same" as in the beginning), but the error persists


Repository with MRE

As you are mounting a volume into /app all changes you are doing inside your container's /app is irrelevant, because it's hidden by the host's directory you are mapping

Do you delete the container between 5 and 7?

@derpirscher I don't understand, does it mean I should mount node_modules not to /app/node_modules but e.g. /node_modules?

@tkausl no I don't delete between 5 and 7, just rebuild (step 7), I assume that if docker has access to node_modules it should be able to update it without deleting the container, right? If I do step 4 instead of step 7 then everything is fine

To achieve the desired behavior where:

node_modules is updated on container startup when package.json changes, without needing to remove volumes
code changes are reflected immediately in the Docker container during development

I had to modify my Dockerfile as follows:

Replaced this:

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

with this:
RUN mkdir -p ./node_modules && chown -R node:node ./node_modules


Replaced this:

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

with this:
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run dev"]

Summary

Removed all COPY instructions, as the files are already available through the mounted volume in docker-compose
Set correct permissions for node_modules
Configured npm install to run at container startup to ensure dependencies are updated when package.json changes

Final Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

USER node

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p ./node_modules && chown -R node:node ./node_modules

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run dev"]


Your Compose file has
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules_docker:/app/node_modules

This means you're not using anything at all from your image.  Of particular note, the node_modules tree comes from a node_modules_docker named volume and not the image, and when you rebuild the image the volume doesn't update (also noted in the other answers to this question).
Becuase both the source code and library tree are built into the image, you don't need this volumes: block and you should delete it.
If you need a live development environment that works on local code, installing Node is strictly easier than installing Docker, especially if your host operating system has a package manager you can use.  It still makes sense to use Docker for external dependencies; for example if you're developing a front-end application to a service with an HTTP API then you could run the backend and its database in containers while using local tools to develop the Web interface.

The first time you run the container, the contents of /app/node_modules in the image is copied into the node_modules_docker volume because the volume doesn't exist.
When you run it a second time the volume isn't empty, so nothing is copied.
This behavior is documented here.
To make sure that the data is always copied, you need to delete the volume. You can do that by deleting it using
docker volume rm <volume name>

or bring the system down with the -v option which tells compose to delete all named volumes in the compose file
docker compose down -v


Thanks for the answer, but I need more clarification. Why can't the contents of a volume be modified after it’s created? This seems cumbersome in development scenarios, especially with Docker, where changes in dependencies require manually remembering to remove the volume. Could this process be automated, perhaps directly in the Dockerfile or through a better mechanism in Docker Compose?

I answered your question. If you have other questions, I suggest making a new post.

My guess would be that you're not deleting all the volumes and images. I faced the same issue with Vue, and btw it actually should work when you rebuild, but it wasn't. So I just deleted the image itself and volumes. If you type docker system prune -af --volumes there were still volumes present, the command doesn't entirely remove all images, volumes and containers. I had to type docker volume prune -a for all the volumes to be removed. So you can try delete everything as you tried before, but before building again, just type docker volume ls and docker image ls to be sure.
One more point:
You're copying everything into the container with copy . . and mounting your root
volumes:
- .:/app
My assumption is your project dir represented by the . (node_modules included). The problem is, docker will pick the node_modules you have locally and replace the node_modules inside the container when you fire up the container. To prove this, try install the dependency locally without docker, then try running the container again, chances are you won't see the error. When you try to run the container, and you're copying he node_modules, that means node will use the dependencies there, inside the node_modules we've copied (the one added missing). I hope that helps.
